# how I can download and install C++ in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, c++

I am a mechanical engineer and I have Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on my Laptop.
I need to install C++ program. How I can do that ?

Help me please

Comment: Are you looking for a full IDE, or just the compiler for C++?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know What is IDE ?

Comment: I want to write my engineering code to solve problems in Openfoam software and in this software C++ programming language is governing.

Comment: Check the duplicate that this is marked as, it explains how to get `g++` which compiles C++ code.  If you are already writing code in Openfoam and it just needs C++ then that's easy.

Answer (score 1):

Just install G++, the C++ compiler of GCC:

```
$ sudo apt install g++
```

You can then compile your source code like this:

```
$ g++ code.cpp -o file
```

This will compile "code.cpp" to "file"